# Issue with validating a form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I need to validate a register form using jQuery. And I tried using jQuery validate method but I am not getting output.

Can anybody help where I am wrong?

I am including what i have done:

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript "> 
    </script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                   $("#form1").validate({
                     rules: {
                    txtfirstname: "required", // simple rule, converted to {required:true} 
                    txtlastname: "required",
                    txtusername: "required",
                    txtpassword: "required",
                    txtemail: {// compound rule 
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    txtaddress: "required",
                    txtstate: "required",
                    txtcity: "required",
                    txtzip: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    txtzip: "Please enter a comment."
                }
              });
            });       

</script>
<form action="" method="post" id="form1">
   <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Firstname</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtfirstname" name="txtfirstname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Lastname</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtlastname" name="txtlastname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Username</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Email</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Address</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtaddress" name="txtaddress" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        State</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtstate" name="txtstate" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        City</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtcity" name="txtcity" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Zip</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtzip" name="txtzip" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnclick" value="SUBMIT" />
                </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this won't fix your issue.. but you only need one or the other - `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.min.js`

Comment: check is you js is loading. I mean relative url you have given that is right  or not..

Comment: Thanks for your reply..then what should i do for validation..

Comment: Yes Ajay, js is loading

Comment: You don't need both the un-minified and minified versions of the plugin.  Remove one.  Also, your button needs to be `type="submit"` or the form will not submit on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button isn't triggering the form submit when the button is clicked - so no validation is occuring

change

```
<input type="button" id="btnclick" value="SUBMIT" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="btnclick" value="SUBMIT" />
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G66qC/)

Comment: thanks for your answer its working but unfortunatly my requirement has changed. i have replaced <input type="submit" id="btnclick" value="SUBMIT" /> to  <a id="ancSubmit"><span></span>Submit </a>. so now how validation will occurs.

Comment: @user3301440  all you have to do is trigger the form submit when you click